# Yarn error : Not able to initialize app-log directories in any of the configured local directories

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hadoop-yarn

I am facing an error while using MapReduce :

```
Not able to initialize app-log directories in any of the configured local directories
```

Here is my yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->

<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>2200</value>
      <description>Amount of physical memory, in MB, that can be allocated for containers.</description>
      </property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>500</value>
    </property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
      <value>2000</value>
          </property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
        <value>1</value>
                  </property>

<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores</name>
          <value>2</value>
                            </property>

<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.enable</name>
                <value>false</value>
                </property>

<property>
      <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
            <value>true</value>
              </property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
 <value>/tmp/yarn_logs</value>
 </property>

<property>
 <name>app-log directories</name>
  <value>/tmp/yarn_logs</value>
   </property>

</configuration>
```

As you see I disabled the healthy check to clearly see where the problem is.

Here is what I've already tried :

- Delete the content of the usercache directory from yarn local dirs
- Change the chmod with 777 to be sure there's no problem with this
- Restart all the hadoop services

I keep getting the exact same error. I really don't know what to do next.. Any idea? Thx by advance!

PS : I already checked : all my hadoop services seem up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : i just removed every files into the hadoop/logs, formated the namenode and restart everything. And my node is healthy again!